# putting one image down when display is flex

Tags: html, css

I've three images next to each other first two is fine but I want third one to be bottom but my code makes all of them inline. I tried `<br>` but not working any solutions?

```html
<div id="sec">
<div class="firstrow">
          <div class="row1">
            <img src="photos/aaaaaaaa.jpg" style="width:480px;height:450px;"/>
        </div>
          <div class="row11">
            <img src="photos/aaa.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="row111">
            <img src="photos/ssss.jpg" style="width:480px;height:700px;"/>
          </div>
        </div></div>
```

```css
#sec {
  width:1180px;
  height:3000px;
  border-right:5px dashed rgba(235, 64, 52,0.5);
  border-left:5px dashed rgba(235, 64, 52,0.5);
  margin:0 auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#sec .firstrow{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top:45px;
}
```

Comment: Show us the picture of the current result? because I can see you have set widths and heights for other images

Comment: @MosiaThabo prnt.sc/s1m91y here. btw I don't know why but all of them are out of `#sec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#sec .firstrow{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap /* added this */
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top:45px;
}
```

And then on your last image

```
.row111{
   flex-basis: 100%; /* force it to take full-width*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
      .row111 img { display:block; }
```